How to make the output of an Op Amp equal to zero in non-inverting amplifier circuit?
I'm using TL072 with the attached circuit in order to make a 3x gain. The AO2 signal comes from DAC of uC which is changing from 0 to 3.3V. But when AO2 is lower than 0.8V, the output signal (T_ref) will be saturated and I can not make a (for example) 0V or 1V output with this circuit.
How can I convert a 0-3.3V signal to 0-10V with an OpAmp?


I suggest you review your understanding of Operational Amplifiers and their internal circuitry in a general way. Most OpAmps need a minimum input CM level, as specified in their respective datasheet.

Your best bet is probably to use a "single-supply" or Rail-to-Rail I/O (RRIO) op-amp.
The one you have neither will work properly with inputs close to the negative supply rail nor can the output swing to the negative rail.
You could also provide it with a negative supply (say -5V) and then it would work properly.
For example, if your accuracy requirements are modest (as the TL072 implies), half of an LM358 dual would work fine.
Note that assumes  that your load is between ground and the op-amp output. If the op-amp is required to sink current and you need good accuracy near 0V out, you probably need the negative rail, or a more suitable op-amp than the LM358 which has around a diode drop at the output when sinking more than a few tens of uA.

The data sheet for the op amp you're using specifies that the closest the output can get to the negative power supply is minimally about a tenth of a volt (look at the "output swing) from the negative rail, and can reach a volt under higher-current circumstances.
So, to hit 0V, you need to provide a negative power supply to the op amp, or switch to an op amp that is closer to rail-to-rail on the output.
There are also problems with the input voltage.  The data sheet specified input common mode voltage needs to be at least 1.5V above the negative rail.  Same solution -- provide a negative power rail, or use an op amp that is truly rail to rail on the input.

As already suggested you need to use a negative rail or use a RRIO op amp. Otherwise you can level shift the inputs and outputs such as an emitter follower on the output and use a resistive divider from the inputs to a ref voltage, but this would not be the best solution.
